# How to format drive in FAT 16 format using VB.NET without user interaction

Tags: vb.net, format, drive

How to format drive in FAT 16 format using VB.NET without user interaction

Comment: Without even a warning message "are you sure?" Format what *kind* of drive?

Comment: Its USB drive, its user requirement after successful copy of files, it should format drive to FAT 16 without any user interaction

Comment: Can anyone help please on this issue?

Comment: This has already been asked and answered, only in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232398/how-to-programically-format-sd-card-on-fat16-on-windows-net

Comment: But it does not work for vb.net

Comment: @amita : I answered with a translation of the c# code. Can you point out what is not working in it if you still have an issue with this code ? It seems to be working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the VB.NET translation of [this C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232398/how-to-programically-format-sd-card-on-fat16-on-windows-net/1492147#1492147) to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232398/how-to-programically-format-sd-card-on-fat16-on-windows-net) :

```
Dim allDrives As DriveInfo() = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
For Each d As DriveInfo In allDrives
    If d.IsReady AndAlso (d.DriveType = DriveType.Removable) Then
        Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
        startInfo.FileName = "format.com"
        startInfo.Arguments = "/fs:FAT /v:MyVolume /q " & d.Name.Remove(2)
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True

        Dim p As Process = Process.Start(startInfo)

        Dim processInputStream As StreamWriter = p.StandardInput
        processInputStream.Write(vbCr & vbLf)


        p.WaitForExit()
    End If
Next
```